# Wrong value for NSView _frame Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, height, frame, nsview

I want to draw a circle 160x160 in the upper right corner of a suclassed NSView named **SettingsViewer**. I must admit that I´m pretty new in this drawing business ;( Although I´ve done some drawing before which was completely different from what I´m doing right now but more complex I have a problem this time.

I linked my SettingsViewer to an **IBOutlet SettingsViewer *myView;** in my SettingsViewer.h to draw this circle by using a button for testing.

The first thing I do is to find out the bounds of my view area like this:

```
NSRect circleBounds = myView->_frame;
```

That´s what I did before and it worked fine. But here I get the correct value for width and a strange value for height:

[image: Debugger Info]
height should be 407.

Any clues why I got this wrong value?

Ronald Hofmann

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `-drawRect:`:

```
-(void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect
{
    CGRect bounds = self.bounds ;
    NSBezierPath * path = [ NSBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:(NSRect){ 
        { CGRectGetMaxX( bounds ) - 160.0f, CGRectGetMaxY( bounds ) - 160.0f }
        , { 160.0f, 160.0f } 
    } ] ;
    [ path stroke ] ;
}
```

Comment: If you want your circle to be 160x160, just ignore the frame of your view. Also, inside the view your drawing canvas/coordinates are given by bounds. Frame indicates the extent of the view in its superview.

Comment: >Frame indicates the extent of the view in its superview: Aha
I did some more testing and found out when I´m adding this line: circleBounds = myView->_bounds;
I´m getting the correct values.

Comment: Why doesn´t this work when I use it in an IBAction? It works in a drawRect though.

Comment: Also, don't use _bounds and _frame--Those are probably internal properties of `NSView`. It's correct to use `[ self frame ]` or `[ self bounds ]`

Comment: Your drawing context is set up before -drawRect: is called. You cannot draw outside of `-drawRect:` If you want your view to be redrawn you request it with `[ self setNeedsDisplay:YES ]` and `drawRect:` will be called at some future time.

Answer (score 1):

> > Why doesn't this work when I use it in an IBAction?

Because the only time that your know you have a valid drawing context is in the drawRect method. If an IBAction need to update a view it should use [theView setNeedsDisplay:YES].

Comment: yes, I found that this was what I did in my first drawing experience.